# Longest intelligible sentence with words of two or fewer letters

Tags: language

The task is to find the longest intelligible and grammatical English sentence containing only words of two or fewer letters.

To limit the possibilities, you may use only the following words:

1. Single letter words, "I" (pronoun), "A" or "a" (indefinite article)
2. Two letter words listed here https://www.lexico.com/explore/two-letter-words

Punctuation is allowed as long as it doesn't end the sentence prematurely.

---

This is a competition. I hope that's allowed. I'll start by introducing myself (or at least my gender).

*I am a he, Hi!*

---

Note: Hints about which tags to use, gratefully accepted.

Comment: Can I use the same word twice in a sentence?

Comment: What counts as an "intelligible and grammatical English sentence" must be precisely specified -- as-is, the question is subjective. (In addition, it is 'open-ended' in a way that's very similar to the type discussed in [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles), making it off-topic for this site.)

Comment: Put a time limit like a week or so, and then accept an answer. Really interesting question by the way.

Comment: Try putting this question in english language use SE. Its a shame that it' s not allowed on puzzling.

Comment: I imagine it might be a sentence with structure similar to "if he is XX, or if he is XX, or if he is XX...so am I."

Comment: Famous motivational quote consisting of only two-letter words: "If it is to be, it is up to me."

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I'll try to redesign and then submit a new improved version.

Comment: @Deusovi - I think I can salvage this, but I'll have to create a new question. Can I sandbox my new improved version on Meta before resubmitting?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I don't think it's likely that it can be easily "salvaged" - this question seems to be inherently open-ended in the same way that linked meta post explains, and it also seems to depend on the precise grammar of English. (But I'm not ruling it out entirely.) I don't think we have a sandbox post for non-riddles -- I'm sure if you mentioned it in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), though, people would be happy to give feedback.

Comment: @ Deusovi - Thanks for your reply and the suggestion to use chat. I notice that there is a current question (very popular and rightly so IMO) that has been shown to have infinite answers - it's still open as I write. I can certainly avoid this trap in one stroke with a rewrite. I just need to define the grammar more carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an interesting observation: conjunctions like `or` or `so` are very powerful, they allow you to link multiple short sentences together

> I am a he or he is a he, so I am an ox or he is an ox.

You could theoretically make a sentence infinitely long that's *technically* grammatically correct (even though it makes no sense)

> I am an ox, so I am an ox, so I am an ox, so I am an ox, so I am an ox, so I am an ox, so...

Guess it really depends on the definition of `intelligible and grammatical English sentence`

Comment: The first sentence has "and" and the second is unintelligible.

Comment: @Ankit Yea it was supposed to be "or" - my bad. That has been corrected

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I can now see why the question was closed. I'll try to make a better, less open-ended one.